# Cannot see fonts in Font Menu Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, font-management

I cannot see most of the fonts in Illustrator CS5, I just installed Yosemite OS last night and this morning the font menu isn't working.[image]

Comment: That's a little messed up. I took the Beta and am now running the public release and I have not had this issue. I know that I was having some issues during beta and found this resource.
I would try running through the steps under the [ 6. Clear the font cache](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/troubleshoot-fonts-mac-os-x.html)
this seemed to resolve most of my issues dealing with Font Book.
Are you using an ATM or similar Font Suitcase type program?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here's the solution I found after searching around a bit:

Open the Mac OS X System Preferences and head to ‘Accessibility.’ Once you are in there, select ‘Display’ from the left-hand list and then check the checkbox that says “Reduce transparency.”

After doing that you should be able to see the font list properly again. I don't know why it works, but it does!